# Dialog not displaying when calling from JNI

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have a native `C` function (with *JNI* of course) that should callback a java method to display a dialog but this dialog is never displayed.

This is how this works:

1. C code calls a java method
2. The java method logs something
3. Then it calls `showDialog(SOME_ID)`
4. The `onCreateDialog(SOME_ID)` is called
5. The dialog is constructed using `AlertDialog.Builder`
6. When I call `AlertDialog alert = builder.create()` the application just stops right there (without crashing or freezing) but *only* when this call starts from the C code.

The code is as follows:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case SOME_ID:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Message");
        builder.setPositiveButton(...);
        builder.setNegativeButton(...);

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        System.out.println("...Never called from JNI");
        return alert;
    }
    return null;
}
```

In **6** I mean that I log something before *and* after calling `builder.create()` but the log **after** the `create` method is never called so the method never returns and the dialog is never created. I have a button to trigger the dialog and, as expected, it works.

I did another test, I printed `getApplicationContext()` calling directly from `onCreate()` and from `onCreateDialog()` (called from C code) and it is the same, because one of the first things I thought was that the onCreateDialog() was being called from another Context or something.

Do you have any idea why the dialog is not displaying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that when calling back from JNI the application wasn't on UI Thread so the dialog was never shown. To fix it I used a Handler (on Activity):

```
public final Handler dialogHandler = new Handler(){     
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        showDialog(SOME_ID);
    }   
};
```

So instead of directly call `showDialog()` I do it by calling `dialogHandler.sendMessage()`.